# NSTimer does not schedule enough times of selector

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, nstimer

I am using the following code to update a ui 50 times in 2 seconds which gives 0.04 time interval. However the method updateLabels only gets called 5 or 6 times sometimes far from 50 times. Is this because I block the main thread of anything? Do you guys know how to make it work?

```
self.timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.04
                                     target:self                     
                                   selector:@selector(updateLabels)
                                   userInfo:nil 
                                    repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:self.timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Comment: You should read the documentation for `NSTimer`. There is a whole discussion about how repeating timers really work.

Comment: How do you know that updateLabels is called 5-6 times? Is there a possibility that you run a code inside that method which lasts more than 40ms?

Answer (score 2):

Just like polling is bad, repeated pushes are bad, too.

As @rmaddy said, go read the docs on timers and how they work.

Instead, I'd suggest:

- mark the time
- do an update
- when update is done, check time elapsed
- if > than update interval, do an update
- if < than update interval, do a delayed update

Keep in mind that the above is probably not quite what you want, either.  If you are updating UIKit views, then the updates might be coalesced and drawing might happen on a background thread.  I.e. when the update calculation is done, the screen might not be fully painted.

As well, you *really* don't want to be doing updates N times a second *unless the data is really changing that quickly*.   If it is changing that quickly, then look at `CADisplayLink` and architect your code to target a particular frames per second update rate.   If it isn't changing that quickly, then only update when the data changes;  redrawing the same thing is a waste of battery life.